# How to add the exact page numbers cited for books in the references list/bibliography, not in the text?

Tags: bibtex, lyx, citing, back-referencing

I am wondering if there is a package or an option in LyX that adds the page number to the references list. I don't want to generate a separate bibtex entry for each page cited of the same reference. Also, I don't want to add the page number next to the reference in the text because that is ugly and not accepted. I use `ieeetran` (not `IEEETran`) for referencing in LyX.

LyX gives the option to add something after the citation:
[image],

but this would include it in the text.

[image]

In short, what I'm looking for is something like this:
[image]

(as I said earlier, I can do this by generating a separate bibtex entry for each page cited, but that would be tedious!)

Comment: If you consider using `biblatex-ieee` (possibly making the necessary adjustmlents to fully match `ieeetran.bst`), you have the `pages` or the `note` fields.

Comment: Just to say that this is absolutely not the correct way to manage references and citations. The bibliography entry should include the page range for the entire article when relevant but not specific page numbers for particular references. Citations in text direct the reader to specific pages. Suppose you cite a book 10 times. To find the relevant location, your reader has to check up to 10 pages in that text rather than just one. The point of references is to make it easy for your reader to find the source. If you don't like the page numbers in the text, use footnotes or endnotes instead.

Comment: @cfr, what you are saying is correct if the piece of information cited is located in different pages of the same book and I only cite those specific pages throughout my document, but in the case I am asking about is that the same reference (Handbook) has many different articles that are cited in different places of my thesis. e.g. in Chapter 1, I cite [8, pp. 16-23] and in Chapter 5 I cite the same reference, but different pages since they are different topics and articles [8, pp. 85,92].

Comment: But then those articles should be separate entries in your bibliography. For example, one should be for the first article with the page range specified from the first to last page of the chapter. Another should be for the next article with the page range specified from the first to last page of that chapter. If you cite specific pages within those articles, those specific pages go in the text or in a note (e.g. 85 or 92 or 16-22 or whatever). If the book has a single author, you could use a single entry in the bibliography. If not, you definitely cannot. A page range for an article

Comment: can go in the bibliography if it is included in its own right as a separate entry. With a handbook, this would usually be the case and you might have several entries each for different articles in the handbook. Each then specifies the first and last page of the article. When you cite these in your text, you specify either the article generally or specific pages from that particular article. That information belongs in the text or a note and not in the bibliography.

Answer (score 4):

A possible, yet sort of hacky solution to this, would be to use the **note** field in your bibliography entry. This would usually print it out in your bibliography but not in the individual references in your thesis.

Depending on your bibliography style and bibliography engine, there might be better ways with proper support, but the notes field should do the thing.

Comment: How to do this in LyX?

Comment: The program/file, which is your bibliography (your bib file). In that, you can add a note field for the entry in discussion, include "p. 8:93" there and hope that the notes field get rendered. This has nothing to do with lyx but with the contents of your bib file and your bibliography style.

Comment: I think this is what Abdulaziz said he was trying to avoid when he said "I don't want to generate a separate bibtex entry for each page cited of the same reference".

Comment: he doesn't need to generate separate bibtex items in the proposed solution. He just needs to add the page number specifications in the notes field of the mentioned entry.